# Referencing figure in text question!

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, color

How to add that sky or blue text color when referencing the figure in text.
That's not in figure section, just a normal paragraph.
For example, in the beginning of the paragraph

Fig1. demonstrate the proposed mechanism of blah blah blah

I wanna make that fig.1. blue or sky color but I can't find the way

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us more about how you currently create cross-references. Please also tell us more about (a) which document class you employ and (b) whether the coloring of the cross-references should apply to all cross-references or only to those of type `figure`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use the package `hyperref` for the referencing in combination with `xcolor` to enable the color SkyBlue.

In your preambles, you have to add

```
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=SkyBlue]{hyperref}
```

you should generally call `hyperref` after you call all other packages with a few exceptions.

If you have labeled your figure with `\label{fig1}`, you can then reference it with `\autoref{fig1}`. Here is a simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=SkyBlue]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{this is figure 1}\label{fig1}
\end{figure}
    This links to \autoref{fig1}
\end{document}
```

Please note that hyperref will turn all internal references to links in various colours. You can change those individually to the colors you want.